# Unable to see drives using PERC H310 in IT mode with PowerEdge R710

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I flashed IT firmware to the PERC H310. I tried with the FW by DELL and LSI (version 20) and both of them didn't work. It looks like the controller is able to see the drives connected directly but cannot see the drives after the backplane of the PowerEdge R710.

When flashing I did this for the LSI FW (version 20: 9211-8i_Package_P20_IR_IT_Firmware):

```
sas2flash -o -f 2118it.bin -b mptsas2.rom
```

and this for DELL FW

```
sas2flash -o -f 6gbpsas.fw -b mptsas2.rom
```

It looks like the controller was flashed correctly. I am able to enter to its BIOS and if I connect a disk by a SFF-8087 - SATA cable I can see it. When I connect the controller to the server's backplane with 36 pin SFF-8087 - SFF-8087 cable I see no drives ( I have 6 drives and they were working with the previous controller).

Do you have any ideas why this is not working? May it be because of generic (non DELL) SFF cable? Or maybe I need to set up some advanced properties of the controller like for example spin timings?